# Adding UIPinchGestureRecognizer on a UIImageview which is subview of UIScrollview's

Tags: iphone

I am using one UIScrollview and UIimageview which is the subview of UIScrollview, and I want to use UIPinchgesturerecognizer on UIImageview, but it is not working.

Comment: enable the userInteraction of the imageview.

Comment: Post the existing code.

Comment: @Rakesh I posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple, you can use it like this :

```
yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:yourImage];
[yourScrollView addSubview:yourImageView];
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[sibgleTap release];
```

GoodLuck.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer after googling, I dissable all gesture of scrollview and then set userinteraction of UIImageview YES, I dissable gesture of UIScrollview using the this code

```
 for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in [scrollviewFrame1 gestureRecognizers]) {
            if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {
                [recognizer setEnabled:NO];
            }
        }
```